# Canadian D-Sign for over sized loads

Tags: road-signs

The following [sign](https://www.alberta.ca/other-signs.aspx) indicates a wide load is being transported. But what does the letter D stand for in this case? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: "D" stands for Overdimensional in Canada. In the US, the Wide Load is used. This sign covers both countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The D sign is for any overdimensional (not just too wide) loads.

The "D" stands for Over**D**imensional and ***D**imensions excédentaires*, introduced by the national harmonization process (agreed to in 1988 and [continues today](https://comt.ca/english/programs/trucking/Index.html)). The reason is *probably* the same as why there are more other pictorial signs in Canada compared to U.S., i.e., official bilingualism (and official unilingualism in Quebec). A bilingual "WIDE LOAD / CHARGE TROP LARGE" or "OVERSIZE LOAD / CONVOI EXCEPTIONNEL (or even longer, CHARGE DE DIMENSIONS EXCÉDENTAIRES)" would be confusing and less comprehensible due to space constraints on a sign. A monolingual sign hinders interprovincial and international commerce if Quebec insists on French signs.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!